# WPF Binding: How to set Binding Source inside UserControl XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to set UserControl's Property like below.
How can I achieve this?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Class}">
      <UserControls:ClassBlock classInstance="{Binding PropertyFromClass}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Set the DataContext on either the HierarchicalDataTemplate or the ClassBlock control.

Comment: I dont have problems with accessing "classInstance" Property. There is problem with telling xaml to get "PorpertFromClass" from "Class" but it tries to get it from ClassBlock

Comment: Right, because you haven't set DataContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext of the user control. It currently does not know where to fetch PropertyFromClass. You can do it like such:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Class}">
    <UserControls:ClassBlock classInstance="{Binding PropertyFromClass}">
        <UserControls:ClassBlock.DataContext>
            <MyViewModels:SomeViewModelHavingPropertyFromClass />
        </UserControls:ClassBlock.DataContext>
    </UserControls:ClassBlock
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

If your property is a property in your code-behind `ClassBlock.Xaml.cs` file, which it sounds like it might be, you must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the property.

### UserControl

```
public partial class ClassBlock: UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    private string classInstance;

    public ClassBlock()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ClassInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return this.classInstance;
        }

        set
        {
            this.classInstance= value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // Invoke the event handlers attached by other objects.
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Class}">
    <!-- Upper case ClassInstance -->
    <UserControls:ClassBlock ClassInstance="{Binding PropertyFromClass}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

That would fix the issue, although that *really* should be in your `View Model`. Take a look at the [MVVM Pattern documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to help out.